# MediaWiki page edit causes "Load denied by X-Frame-Options: does not permit cross-origin framing"

Tags: dns, mediawiki, frames

I am running a MediaWiki on a VM, accessing it through http://12.34.56.78/wiki -- I was able to edit pages.

Now I've redirected my domain http://foo.org to http://12.34.56.78/wiki

http://foo.org/wiki does indeed find my wiki, but when I attempt to edit a page I get a blank page. Inspecting the console yields:

> ***Load denied by X-Frame-Options: does not permit cross-origin framing***

What is the cause of the problem? And what is the solution?

Comment: The problem is probably that there are still links pointing to `12.34.56.78` rather than `foo.org` in your Wiki install - perhaps through a configuration setting you haven't updated yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like you are using "frame-redirects" from http://foo.org to http://12.34.56.78/wiki. Frame redirects are a nasty hack and often cause problems, like the one above.

You should use actual http (reverse) proxying, or a domain alias (cname) and rewrite rules. The difference is that with the proxy, the data is actually traveling through an intermediate web server (the proxy), while with the cname+rewrite, it's just two names for the same box.

Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection to understand all the different kinds of forwarding and redirection.

Comment: Thanks, setting `$wgServer` to `"http://pipad.org"` in `LocalSettings.php` and logging into my domain provider and replacing the URL forwarding records with A records fixed it!